# Excel 2016 no more columns available

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was given a spreadsheet to work on that was created by someone else.  After column IV, there are no more columns only one large shaded area.

Comment: Is the file saves as an `.XLS`?

Comment: What have you tried already? If possible, upload a screen shot of your sheet too, that helps diagnose the problem.

Comment: consider to right click on the column header ostensibly to adjust the column width, to see what number returns. If too large, the column will not be visible in the window. Also consider to use goto with a column designator beyond IV

Comment: the go to function comes back with "this formula is missing a range reference or a defined name

Comment: okay, stupid question.  How do I upload a screen shot here?

Comment: I've tried eliminating print areas, frozen panes, removed page breaks.  The person that set this up knows less than I do so I do not think they did anything intentional.

Comment: You don't have permission to post images yet. Post a link to an image-hosting service (and try to answer questions people as you...)

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post.  I did answer your question regarding the .XLS extension.  "yes"  Were you able to see that?

Comment: @user877520 whoops! Forgot about the picture posting limitations. I hope you're able to find value here at Superuser and can help others with answers to their questions! You'll have plenty of positive rankings in no time. Glad you found your answer.

Comment: Do you have similar display in other Sheets or are normal? If yes then go to that Sheet, reach to Column IV, Select it and Change the Width to be normal look. Other is, select the Sheet Tab, Right Click, hit view code, open Immediate windows and write, Columns("IV").ColumnWidth = 10. Hope this work.

Answer (score 2):

1) Open the file

2) Save as an `XLSX`

3) Close it

4) Open the `XLSX` file.

You should be good after that. Let us know either way

Comment: Are you sure this will restore the Column IV?

Comment: `.XLS` has a column limit of 255 (i.e. IV), saving as `.XLSX`, which has 16K columns should fix the problem

Comment: But the OP is already using Version 2016 and it's Workbook's file extension is .XLSX !

Comment: OP answered "yes" to my question about the file being saved as `.XLS` so _not_ using `.XLSX. Newer versions of Excel still limit you to 255 columns to not break `.XLS` file format.

Comment: still you are not getting my point,, I want to say that you have suggested to save the File as XLSX, which is file extension of Ver 2010 and higher. Since OP is using 2016 has more that 10 K Columns by default,, so in this case again save the 2016 File as XLSX doesn't makes any sense !!